# Wordpress echo meta keywords in body

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, keyword, meta

I would like to display meta keywords of each wordpress page in the body (with PHP).
I found that "echo WPSEO_Frontend::metadesc();" display the meta description but i could find any way to display the keywords in the body.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Many thanks,

Bentzy.

Answer (score 1):

`WPSEO_Frontend::metakeywords();` Outputs the meta keywords element.

http://yoast.com/docs/wordpress-seo/Frontend/WPSEO_Frontend.html#methodmetakeywords

Comment: I tried the following line on php:  
echo WPSEO_Frontend::metakeywords();
 
and get this error 
"Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context " 
on line 863 which is:
if ( ! isset( $this->options['usemetakeywords'] ) || ! $this->options['usemetakeywords'] )